# Upgrading Redmine from 1.0.1 to 1.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upgrade, redmine

I did everything from http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/RedmineUpgrade :

> hosting_aleynikov@lithium:~/projects/redmine$ cd redmine-1.0.3
> hosting_aleynikov@lithium:~/projects/redmine/redmine-1.0.3$
> rake generate_session_store (in
> /var/www/home/hosting_aleynikov/projects/redmine/redmine-1.0.3)
> hosting_aleynikov@lithium:~/projects/redmine/redmine-1.0.3$
> rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
> (in
> /var/www/home/hosting_aleynikov/projects/redmine/redmine-1.0.3)
> hosting_aleynikov@lithium:~/projects/redmine/redmine-1.0.3$
> rake
> db:migrate:upgrade_plugin_migrations
> RAILS_ENV=production (in
> /var/www/home/hosting_aleynikov/projects/redmine/redmine-1.0.3)
> Cannot find old migration table -
> assuming nothing needs to be done
> hosting_aleynikov@lithium:~/projects/redmine/redmine-1.0.3$
> rake db:migrate_plugins
> RAILS_ENV=production (in
> /var/www/home/hosting_aleynikov/projects/redmine/redmine-1.0.3)
>
> Migrating engines... Migrating
>
> acts_as_activity_provider... Migrating
>
> acts_as_attachable... Migrating
>
> acts_as_customizable... Migrating
>
> acts_as_event... Migrating
>
> acts_as_list... Migrating
>
> acts_as_searchable... Migrating
>
> acts_as_tree... Migrating
>
> acts_as_versioned... Migrating
>
> acts_as_watchable... Migrating
>
> awesome_nested_set... Migrating
>
> classic_pagination... Migrating
>
> coderay-0.9.2... Migrating
>
> google_analytics_plugin... Migrating
>
> gravatar... Migrating
>
> open_id_authentication... Migrating
>
> prepend_engine_views... Migrating
>
> rfpdf... Migrating
>
> ruby-net-ldap-0.0.4...
>
> hosting_aleynikov@lithium:~/projects/redmine/redmine-1.0.3$
> rake tmp:cache:clear(in
> /var/www/home/hosting_aleynikov/projects/redmine/redmine-1.0.3)
> hosting_aleynikov@lithium:~/projects/redmine/redmine-1.0.3$
> rake tmp:sessions:clear (in
> /var/www/home/hosting_aleynikov/projects/redmine/redmine-1.0.3)
> hosting_aleynikov@lithium:~/projects/redmine/redmine-1.0.3$
>
> ls app db extra lib public README.rdoc
>
> test vendor config doc files log
>
> Rakefile script tmp

.......but my version 1.0.1 don't want to upgrade to 1.0.3, because

1. production.log updating in old folder (version 1.0.1)
2. Information in Administration-Information show this: "Redmine 1.0.1.stable (MySQL)"
3. attached files goes into old folder.

Please help to finish it.

Thank to all.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that your web server is simply still using the old installation directory.

Either rename the old directory to redmine_backup_thedate (or something) and rename the new version to what your old install directory was before the rename.

Or change which directory your web server is using for redmine to the new directory instead.